# Distance score between lists using cdist

Tags: python, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have two list of arrays and I want to compute the distance between the lists (first array from first list and first array from second list and so on...) using Euclidean/ Manhattan/ Cosine to find the similarity between the features. Both the lists consists of around 1000 arrays. I want to get a value for each one such that I can classify the features as good/ bad based on a threshold using distance score.

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance
features1= [array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0.00261035]), array([0.033, 0.11, 0.08044308,  0, 0, 0 ,0.5,0.3 ])]
features2 = [array([0, 0, 0 , 0 , 0,0.00215861]), array([0, 0 , 0.01098017,0     , 0,0.00215914 , 0.7, 0.9])]
dist = distance.cdist(features1, features2, 'euclidean')
print(dist)
```

I get value error when I try to execute this.

```
ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.
```

Edit:
I'm not able to figure out the error.
For example in my first if I have two arrays of size (512,) , (380,)
In my second list, I have two arrays of size (512,) ,(380,)
I want compare corresponding arrays for distance scores.I also tried to use linalg.

```
print(np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(features1,features2)))
```

I get this error.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512,) (380,)
```

Comment: please replace with actual code (the ellipsis causes errors)

Comment: Also, I get no error from the code above (after removing the ellipses).  Reset your interpreter and try the above code again

Comment: After removing the ellipsis, I don't get any error. Kindly re-check your data.

Comment: I have around 20000 elements in each list, I cannot add all of time

Comment: Does this answer your quesetion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773537/python-cdist-error-valueerror-xa-must-be-a-2-dimensional-array

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidHaris  Please check the edited code and see if you now try to understand my problem.